# count number of rows with laravel according to my search

Tags: laravel

I would like to count the number of rows according to my search. How could I add it to my controller

```
     $ventas = Venta::join('personas','ventas.idcliente','=','personas.id')
        ->join('users','ventas.idusuario','=','users.id')
        ->select('ventas.id','ventas.tipo_comprobante',
        'ventas.created_at','ventas.efectivo','ventas.efectivo1','ventas.tarjeta','ventas.vales','ventas.cambio','ventas.total',
        'ventas.estado','personas.nombre','users.usuario')
        ->whereDate($criterio, '>=', $buscar)
        ->whereDate($criterio1, '<=', $buscar1)
        ->orderBy('ventas.id', 'desc');
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could do so by simply doing something like this:

```php
$count = $ventas->count();
```

Would that work for your purposes?

**EDIT**

To retrieve the data in a Laravel only application, at the bottom of your controller action/method you would have something like this:

```php
return view('yourblade.path.file', compact($count, $ventas));
```

Then in your blade/view file you could get the count by doing something like this inside of `<p>` tags:

```html
<p>{{$count}}</p>
```

If you are requesting the data from an endpoint call in a Vue template you could call the endpoint which corresponds to your Laravel controller action, and inside that action just return the data itself at the bottom of your controller action/method doing something like this:

```php
return $count->toJson();
```

Then when processing the request on the Vue side, store it with whatever variable you are using.  Then you can retrieve that from inside of `<p>` tags doing something like this:

```html
<p>{{this.yourVueCount}}</p>
```

Comment: and the value of count as I show for example in a <p> with vuejs

Comment: @ChristianAldana I updated my answer.  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @ChristianAldana I updated my answer to include both the Laravel way and the way you could get the data in Vue.  Will you also please update your question to include your question about Vue and add that tag?